# Number of ways of selecting unordered pair of proper subsets

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

$X = \{1, 2, 3, 4, ...... 2017\}$ and $A \subsetneqq X$ ; $B \subsetneqq X$ ; $A \cup B \subsetneqq X$.

Then number of ways of selecting unordered pair of sets $A$ and $B$ such that $A\cup B \subsetneqq X$.

Provided answer is: $$\frac{4^{2017}-3^{2017}+2^{2017}-1}{2}$$

Now here each element has $4$ options i.e. go to $A$ or go to $B$ or go to both or go to neither. That gives $4^{2017}$ but I can't make out how to proceed further.

An answer is given for this question on this portal but that is incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

As you have noted, each element has four options. So the number of *ordered* pairs of subsets $A,B$ such that $A,B\subseteq X$ is $4^{2017}$. (Note the symbol "$\subseteq$".)

Because of the definition of $\subset$, we must exclude the ordered pairs such that $A\cup B=X$. To count these pairs, note that for each element, there are three options: being in $A$, being in $B$ or being in both. This makes $3^{2017}$ pairs.

So there are $4^{2017}-3^{2017}$ *ordered* pairs. To count the number of unordered pairs $\{A,B\}$ we must note that the pairs that $A\neq B$ are counted twice and the pairs that $A=B$ are counted once. Note also that the case $A=B=X$ is already excluded. Then the number of cases is
$$\frac{4^{2017}-3^{2017}-(2^{2017}-1)}2+(2^{2017}-1)=\frac{4^{2017}-3^{2017}+2^{2017}-1}2$$

Comment: Case where $A=B=X$ is excluded when we subtracted $3^{2017}$?

Comment: @ajotatxe Can you explain more about when you subtracted $(2^{2017}-1)$ and after that you added it too.?